# ¿Cómo eliminar elemento repetido enla lista usando recursión?

Tags: python

```
lista=[1,2,3,1,6,7,1,9,1]                           
lista2=[]
def removeritem(lista,elemento):
  if elemento ==0:
    return 1
  else:
      removeritem=lista.remove(i=1)
      lista2=lista-removeritem(lista.remove(i=1))
    return lista2
```

esta es la lista `[1,2,3,1,6,7,1,9,1]`, y quiero que me retorne otra lista sin elementos repetidos.

Comment: y cual es el problema con tu código?

Comment: Hola, recuerda responder a las preguntas que realiza la comunidad para que te apoyen de una mejor forma, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Ya que se trata de una tarea académica, no estaría bien que te diéramos la solución, pero sí voy a tratar de explicarte en qué consiste la recursión y cómo podría aplicarse a este caso a ver si eres capaz de dar por ti mismo con la respuesta.

La recursión parte de una idea tan sencilla que parece casi magia el que funcione. Simplemente consiste en imaginar que ya tienes una función hecha (sin que sepas cómo funciona) que te resuelve el problema pero para una lista más pequeña de la que tienes, y te hagas la pregunta ¿cómo podría usar esa función para resolver mi problema para una lista mayor?

Es decir, imaginemos que tienes una función llamada `eliminar_repetidos()` a la que le pasas una lista y te retorna otra en la que los elementos repetidos han sido eliminados. A ti te dan la lista `l` y puedes usar esa función pasándole una lista más pequeña (por ejemplo, tu lista `l` salvo el primer elemento) ¿cómo podríamos hacer uso de eso para resolver nuestro problema? Este es el meollo sobre el que tienes que darle vueltas a la cabeza. Piénsalo un poco y sigue leyendo

> Si `l` es la lista "completa", podemos quitarle el primer elemento usando `n = l[0]`, y después podemos pasar el resto de la lista a nuestra función que sabe resolver el problema: `l_sin_duplicados = eliminar_repetidos(l[1:])`
>
>  Una vez esa función ha retornado, tenemos el problema casi resuelto. Si el valor de `n` que extrajimos antes está en `l_sin_duplicados`, el resultado final será `l_sin_duplicados` (pues `n` ya estaba allí y no queremos que se repita. Si en cambio `n` no está en `l_sin_duplicados`, el resultado final será `[n] + l_sin_duplicados` (es decir, volvemos a añadir `n` al principio).

Otra cosa que hay que pensar para dar con la solución recursiva es cómo hay que tratar el caso más pequeño posible, es decir, el de la lista con un solo elemento. Esto suele ser muy sencillo. Si la lista que nos pasan tiene un solo elemento, el resultado será esa lista tal cual (pues no tiene duplicados). Podemos añadir a nuestra función esa condición al principio para que en el caso trivial retorne directamente la solución, y en los casos más complicados haga el truco explicado en el *spoiler*, para invocar a la función que suponemos preexistente y que encuentra la solución para listas más pequeñas. O sea, algo así:

```
si la longitud de la lista es 1, retornar la lista
si no:
  usar la función eliminar_repetidos()
  para una lista más pequeña de modo que resolvamos
  el problema para la lista más grande
retornar el resultado
```

Y ahora viene la ***MAGIA***. La función esa que suponíamos que ya existía ¡es la misma que la que acabamos de escribir! Simplemente cuando había que llamar a aquella función, llamamos a la misma que estamos escribiendo.

Comment: No te imaginas cuánto me ha ayudado tu comentario. Ahora veo la recursión desde otro punto de vista. ¡Millones de gracias!

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a el còdigo que muestras, puedes implementar recursividad en la funciòn removerItemsRepetidos() para que retorne otra lista sin elementos repetidos de esta forma:

```
lista=[1,2,3,1,6,7,1,9,1]      
  
def removerItemsRepetidos(lista):
    nuevalista = []
    if lista == []:
        nuevalista = []
    else:
        if (lista[0] not in lista[1:]):
            nuevalista = [lista[0]] + removerItemsRepetidos(lista[1:])
        else:
            nuevalista = removerItemsRepetidos(lista[1:])
    return nuevalista
```

llama de esta forma la funciòn :

```
print(removerItemsRepetidos(lista))
```

para obtener la siguiente salida sin elementos repetidos:

```
[2, 3, 6, 7, 9, 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

Mira amigo esta es una opcion de hacer lo que tu dices pero con algunos cambios.

```
lista=[1,2,3,1,6,7,1,9,1]                           
lista2=[]

def removerep(lista):
    for i in lista:             #Recorre cada elemento de la lista
        if i not in lista2:     #Ver que elementos no estan en la lista2
           lista2.append(i)      #Asignar esos valores a la lista2 sin numeros repetidos
    return lista2
          
final=removerep(lista)    
print('Lista original: ' + str(lista))
print('Lista sin duplicados: ' + str(final))
```

Espero que este cambio si sea de ayuda, es mas que todo un aporte de lo que he investigado.

Comment: 1. Aquí no se usa recursión 2. No es bueno hacerle la tarea a alguien (aunque no lo has hecho) 3. Lee [answer]

Comment: mi idea no era hacerle la tarea era darle una idea, pero esta bien lo tenre en cuenta para futura preguntas

Comment: Gracias por tu contribuciòn, te sugerimos revisar [ask]. Esta respuesta no usa recursividad, puedes editarla, saludos.