# Función recursiva para sumar y multiplicar una lista en PYTHON

Tags: python, funciones, recursión

Sumar y multiplicar los elementos de una lista, estoy tratando de una aplicar una función recursiva para ambos casos pero no me esta dando el resultado esperado

```
def suma(listaNumeros):
    for numero in listaNumeros: #recorremos la lista por cada numero
    print(numero)
    if numero==listaNumeros[0]:
    print(numero)
    suma(listaNumeros[0 + 1])
    else: 

listaNumeros = [1, 2, 3, 4]
suma(listaNumeros)
```

Comment: Que te da? Que no te da? Que debería darte? Cual es el problema?

Comment: estoy recorriendo los numeros contenidos en una lista con un for, luego imprimo cada numero, si el numero esta en la primera posicion de la lista entonces imprime ese numero nuevamente y vuelve a llamar a la funcion de arriba pero empieza desde la posicion dos, pero estoy un poco perdida

Comment: Pero por que no te funciona? Para que es ese else ?? Y identa bien ese codigo por favor

Comment: Sí estás un poco perdida, sí... si la función se supone que ha de devolverte la suma ¿dónde se estaría realizando esa suma? ¿por qué la función no retorna nada? ¿Por qué haces todos esos print? Puedes empezar por leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/490630/7123) a otra pregunta sobre recursividad, donde se intenta explicar en qué consiste la idea de la recursividad, y después intentas aplicar esa idea a tu caso a ver si te sale y ya nos cuentas.

Answer (score 3):

Por lo que entiendo estas necesitando imprimir el primero de una lista que aparece en orden y al final sumar todos recursivamente.

### Sumar recursivamente

El caso base con lista de tamaño 1 imprime y devuelve la posición cero.

```
def sumar(lista):
    if len(lista) == 1:
        print(lista[0])
        return lista[0]
    else:
        print(lista[0])
        return lista[0] + sumar(lista[1:])



listaNumeros = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print("Total Sumado: ", sumar(listaNumeros))
```

El **resultado** será el print() de los **números en orden** y la **suma** de todos los elementos de la lista.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Total Sumado: 55
```

### Multiplicar recursivamente

Para el caso de querer hacer lo mismo pero con multiplicación:

```
def multiplicacion(lista):
    if len(lista) == 1:
    print(lista[0])
    return lista[0]
else:
    print(lista[0])
    return lista[0] * multiplicacion(lista[1:])
```

Hacemos el print con la función Multiplicación utilizando la misma listaNumeros

```
print("Total Multiplicado: ", multiplicacion(listaNumeros))
```

El resultado es el siguiente: Impresión de números en orden con multiplicación de todos los elementos de la lista.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Total Multiplicado:  3628800
```

Espero que sea de utilidad.